# How can I get the solution of the equation?

Tags: equation-solving

When I try to get the solution of the equation using the following code

```
 NSolve[0.81 + r^2 (-(2/r) + 
 E^((4 \[Pi] (\[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[1/r]))/r) (1 + r^2)^(4 \[Pi])) == 0, r]
```

I get the output as it is:
[image]

I would like to ask how to get the solution of the equation in this case?

Comment: Are you sure it has a solution? FindMinimum suggests that the min is 0.81 for real valued r. FindInstance gives a complex value of 1.0246798601836489` - 1.3571104872260424` I, when it comes close to zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = 81/100 + 
   r^2 (-(2/r) + E^((4 π (π - 2 ArcTan[1/r]))/r) (1 + r^2)^(4 π));

FunctionDomain[expr, r]

(* r < 0 || r > 0 *)

FunctionRange[expr, r, y] // N

(* y >= 0.81 *)
```

Consequently, there is no real root.

To find complex roots,

```
sol = FindRoot[expr == 0, {r, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@
  {1 + I, -1 + I}

(* {{r -> -0.289276963653817 + 1.01028467562375 I}, 
    {r -> -0.00993411402557552 + 0.189641985591974 I}} *)
```

Checking,

```
expr /. sol

(* {0.*10^-12 + 0.*10^-12 I, 0.*10^-12 + 0.*10^-12 I} *)
```